# map.forEach Unexpected return value

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, hashmap, stream

Tenho o seguinte map:

```
private static Map<ParseCreator, Parseable> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Percorro esse map da seguinte forma:

```
for (Map.Entry<ParseCreator, Parseable> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        ParseCreator creator = entry.getKey();
        Parseable parseable = entry.getValue();

        if (parseable.canParse(reader)) {
            return creator.create(reader.getText());
        }
    }
```

Porém se uso o `forEach` do Java 8 tenho o seguinte erro:

```
map.forEach((k,v) -> {
            ParseCreator creator = k;
            Parseable parseable = v;

            if (parseable.canParse(reader)) {
                return creator.create(reader.getText()); //Erro: Unexpected return value
            }
        });
```

Como utilizar o `forEach` corretamente nesse caso?

Comment: O `forEach` retorna `void`, por isto não consegue dar um `return` dentro dele.

Comment: Não é possível usar o forEach nesse caso então, não existe outra implementação que aceite return?

Comment: Na verdade, creio que você pode usar o forEach ainda assim. Você pode ter um `filter` neste `map` com a condição (`if`) que deseja. Algo [assim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48602826/2387977) ou [assim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23407107/2387977)

Comment: Precisamos de mais código para te ajudar. Esse retorno é para qual Objeto? Se não entrar no if, ele não retorna. A função map exige sempre um retorno, então não funcionaria.

Comment: No primeiro exemplo, no qual eu uso atualmente, retorna uma instancia de uma classe pai InvoiceParser. Utilizando os exemplo com filter eu não consegui retornar uma instancia dessa classe, sem falar que o código fica horrível. Acredito que o primeiro exemplo seria o ideal nesse caso pra manter legibilidade do código, ou não?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar um `stream` com os `Entry` deste map, filtrar os que deseja, e depois mapeá-los para o tipo retornado por `create`:

```
Optional<Tipo> result = map
    // obtem um stream com todos Entry do map
    .entrySet().stream()
    // considerar apenas as entradas em que canParse retorna true
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().canParse(reader))
    // chamar o create(reader.getText())
    .map(e -> e.getKey().create(reader.getText()))
    // pegar o primeiro resultado
    .findFirst();
```

Sendo que `Tipo` é o tipo retornado pelo método `create` - como não foi informado, estou deixando um nome "genérico" qualquer, mas basta que você troque pelo tipo que você está usando.

Outro detalhe é que este código retorna um `Optional`, ou seja, pode ser que não encontre nenhum resultado, e a vantagem do `Optional` é que você pode escolher o que fazer caso ele não tenha nenhum resultado.

Por exemplo, você pode simplesmente retornar o valor:

```
return result.get();
```

Mas caso o `filter` não tenha encontrado nenhuma entrada que satisfaça a condição (no caso, para nenhuma delas `canParse` retornou `true`), o `Optional` não terá um valor e o `get()` lançará um `NoSuchElementException`.

Como alternativa, você pode definir um valor default para ser retornado, caso o `Optional` esteja sem valor:

```
return result.orElse(valorDefault);
```

Sendo que `valorDefault` é qualquer valor que você quiser retornar, caso nenhum seja encontrado pelo `filter` (podendo ser até mesmo `null`).

Outra opção é [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-), que é similar, mas recebe um [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) que produz o valor default:

```
return result.orElseGet(() -> valorDefault);
```

A diferença entre `orElse` e `orElseGet` é explicada em detalhes [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438340/112052).

---

Ou você pode escolher lançar uma exceção (que não seja a `NoSuchElementException`):

```
return result.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```

E se caso precisar passar argumentos ao construtor da Exception:

```
return result.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(argumentos))
```

Enfim, com `Optional` você pode escolher qual ação tomar caso não tenha encontrado nenhum valor. [Veja a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) para saber todas as opções.