# Qual a diferença entre os métodos orElse() e orElseGet() do java.util.Optional?

Tags: java, java-8

Qual a diferença entre os métodos [`orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) e [`orElseGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-), da classe [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ambos retornam algo se o [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) não tiver um valor.

A diferença é no [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) você fornece o valor a ser retornado, e no [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) você fornece um [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) (um objeto que retorna o valor). Ex:

```
Optional<String> opt = Optional.empty();

System.out.println(opt.orElse("ola"));
System.out.println(opt.orElseGet(() -> "ola"));
```

Ambos imprimem `"ola"`. Evidentemente que dentro do `orElseGet` você pode criar um método tão complexo quanto queira:

```
System.out.println(opt.orElseGet(() -> {
    // faz outras coisas complexas aqui
    return resultadoDasCoisasComplexasAcima;
}));
```

Mas nada impede que o método que faz várias coisas complexas sejam chamado diretamente e o resultado passado para `orElse`:

```
System.out.println(opt.orElse(metodoQueFazVariasCoisasComplexas()));
```

A diferença é que nesse caso o método é chamado e seu retorno é passado para `orElse`. Já se eu chamar `orElseGet`, o método só é chamado se o `Optional` não tiver um valor:

```
public String metodo() {
    System.out.println("dentro do método");
    return "ola";
}
...

Optional<String> opt = Optional.empty();
System.out.println(opt.orElse(metodo()));
System.out.println(opt.orElseGet(() -> metodo()));
```

Como o `Optional` é vazio, ambos chamarão pelo método. A saída é:

```
dentro do método
ola
dentro do método
ola
```

Mas se o `Optional` não for vazio:

```
Optional<String> opt = Optional.of("teste");
System.out.println(opt.orElse(metodo()));
System.out.println(opt.orElseGet(() -> metodo()));
```

O método só é chamado no primeiro caso, pois o retorno dele deve ser passado para `orElse`. Já o `orElseGet` só chama o método se o `Optional` for vazio (então neste caso, ele não é chamado). A saída é:

```
dentro do método
teste
teste
```

Isso faz diferença nos casos em que o método a ser chamado é muito custoso (faz operações complexas, demoradas, gasta muito processamento ou memória, o objeto retornado é "muito grande", etc). Nesses casos, usar `orElseGet` é uma opção melhor que `orElse`, pois aí o método só é chamado quando realmente necessário.

E como citado [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438340/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-m%C3%A9todos-orelse-e-orelseget-do-java-util-optional/438341#comment846884_438341), existe ainda o método [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-), que recebe um `Supplier` que cria uma exceção. Neste caso, a exceção é lançada caso o `Optional` seja vazio:

```
Optional<String> opt = Optional.empty();
String valor = opt.orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

No código acima, como o `Optional` é vazio, será lançado um `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Eu colocaria o caso de necessidade real: quando o valor default é pesado de ser gerado. Mas como (tirando esse detalhe) sua resposta seria igual à que eu colocaria, fica a sugestão de melhoria =)

Comment: Talvez pudesse colocar como curiosidade a questão do `orElseThrow`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Resposta atualizada, obrigado pelas sugestões!

Answer (score -1):

O método **orElse()** sempre irá executar o retorno esperado que fora passado dentro dele, ainda que o valor do Optional não seja null.

[Método orElse() diretamente da Java Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0o6V.png)

O método **orElseGet()**, dado que recebe um supplier na sua sintaxe, executará o retorno se e somente se o optional anterior for nulo.

[Método orElseGet() diretamente da Java Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XePeb.png)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).